# Could not find package * at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your min imum-stability

Tags: php, magento-2.1, composer

Kindly help me on this error I get when I run this command:

[image]

The extension's composer.json:

```
{
"name": "veriteworks/m2-price",
"type": "magento2-module",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"description": "Magento2 extension for Price.",
"version": "1.0.4",
"authors":[
    {
        "name": "Hirokazu Nishi",
        "email": "nishi@veriteworks.co.jp",
        "homepage": "http://veriteworks.co.jp/",
        "role": "developer"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.2",
    "magento/module-store": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-backend": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "~100.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0",
    "lib-libxml": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Veriteworks\\Price\\": ""
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did the vendor provide a private repository? The only module by this vendor listed on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) is `veriteworks/m2-japaneselocale`

Comment: @DannyNimmo According to the installation manual, I executed this command `composer config repositories.veriteworksartifacts artifact ¥
/<Magento Installation Directory>/vendor/veriteworks/packages`

Comment: An [artifact repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact) is simply a folder containing zip files. Assuming the vendor provided you with a zip, check that you're passing in the correct path to this folder.

Comment: @DannyNimmo Now I know what is wrong. I-unzip the file. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Posting my comments here as an answer.*

Check that the module is listed on a public repository. If the vendor provided a private repository, check that this is accessible and configured correctly in your project's own `composer.json`.

In this case, the vendor provided instructions to use an [artifact repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#artifact) which is a folder on your local machine which should contain zip file packages of the module.

Comment: I had a similar problem, apparently I had 2 different magento.com accounts, and I was using user/pass on the one that did not have the package I was trying to install purchased! I switched the user/pass on `~/.composer/auth.json` for repo.magento.com to the other one, and it worked.